# group gird extjs 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I am having almost the same error on collapseGroup method when I click to collapse, it expects group parameter, but this paremeter is get in only
isCollapsed: false
**proto**: object and not children array property. Maybe there is missing some settings. Any help why groupsummary is not showing collapsed.

Comment: I also have the same problem

Comment: this is error of 4.2 it's fix in sencha 5.0